Name of trichotomy-like relation property
If $R$ is a binary relation on some set $S$, then we call $R$ antisymmetric if $\forall x,y\in S,~~ x=y\vee (\neg xRy) \vee (\neg yRx)$.
A natural counterpart is the property $$\color{red}{\forall x,y\in S,~~ x=y\vee xRy \vee yRx.}$$
I have been calling this trichotomous, but I have learned that this term is more commonly used with exclusive or rather than inclusive or.  That is, it seems to be standard that $R$ is trichotomous if exactly one of $\{x=y,~ xRy,~ yRx\}$ holds for every $x,y\in S$.  This is all fine, but not as useful pedagogically since it is harder to work with and incompatible with other properties like reflexivity.
This leads to my question: if not trichotomous, then what is the standard name for the natural property, given above in red?  Supporting references published in mainstream journals would be most helpful.

Not sure why you find trichotomy hard to work with pedagogically.  The best way to teach relations IMHO is to make students understand that they have seen many of them already, and we are now unifying and slightly formalising these concepts.  In particular, they should already be very familiar with an exceedingly important relation which satisfies trichotomy, namely, $<$ on $\mathbb R$.

Trichotomy is easy enough to introduce pedagogically, but when it comes to proving things with it using the very primitive tools in a first course (e.g. modus ponens) it is awkward.  Even expressing it in propositional calculus is a mess.

One name I've seen for this type of relation is "connected" (Wikipedia article) (alternatively, "complete" or "total"), defined in one of a couple of equivalent ways as a relation $R$ on $S$ such that

$\forall x,y \in S$, $x=y$ or $xRy$ or $yRx$
If $x,y \in S$ and $x \ne y$, then $xRy$ or $yRx$


Thank you!  From the wiki article, looks like the terminology here is a mess.
